# SVG background + css - How can this animate like this?

Tags: css, svg

So I've seen this crazy nice effect on Carrd.co and I don't understand how this is able to animate.

```css
.pizza {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 2em 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("https://carrd.co/assets/images/bg.svg"),linear-gradient(45deg, #6E436C 25%, #2A4584 75%);
    background-size: cover, cover;
    background-position: top, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="pizza">
  
</div>
```

If someone can explain this to me that would be nice. What makes the svg to animate?

Comment: best way to learn in my opinion is to open web developer tool and start turning properties on and off and see what happens.  Try changing some values, etc...  At least I find that this is what helps me understand css properties the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping css keyframes animation within the SVG targeting each polygon to fade in and out. Like so:

```
@keyframes foo {
  0% { opacity: 1; } 
  20% { opacity: 0.25; } 
  40% { opacity: 1.0; } 
  60% { opacity: 0.55; } 
  80% { opacity: 0.25; } 
  100% { opacity: 1; } 
} 

polygon.a1 { animation: foo ease 10s infinite; } 
polygon.f1 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.0125); } 
polygon.d1 { animation-delay: 0.5s; }
```

Comment: Oh, I see, the animation is in the .svg file! I thought the CSS made it fade in and out. Well, thanks for waking me up sir.